# Java to Python RSA

Tags: java, python, rsa, bouncycastle, m2crypto

I'm trying to encrypt a string from Java to Python, using the library Bouncy Castle J2ME on the client side and Python M2Crypto on the other.

Everything is pretty good, I can decrypt it properly, but the padding is the issue.

The M2Crypto lib gives me (as far as I can tell) only these Padding schemes:
no_padding = 3
pkcs1_padding = 1
sslv23_padding = 2
pkcs1_oaep_padding = 4

While the bouncy castle J2ME only provides:
NoPadding
OAEPWithAndPadding
PKCS5Padding
SSL3Padding

So, I can use NoPadding between both, but then the strings that get generated after decryption are filled with jumbled characters.

I'd really like to get the padding sorted out, but I don't know how to convert between padding schemes / if that's even possible.

Please help me figure this out, it's killing me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Bouncy Castle but I guess you somehow use [`RSAEngine`](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.6/org/bouncycastle/crypto/engines/RSAEngine.html) which implements [`AsymmetricBlockCipher`](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.6/org/bouncycastle/crypto/AsymmetricBlockCipher.html) thus you should be able to use [`PKCS1`](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.6/org/bouncycastle/crypto/encodings/PKCS1Encoding.html) or not?

And there also seems to be [`OAEP`](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.6/org/bouncycastle/crypto/encodings/OAEPEncoding.html) support, which given the right parameters should also work.

Comment: I guess I was.  I posted this after hours of tinkering in desperation, and lo and behold it was something rather simple.

It turns out, if I use the string "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding" with the "BC" provider, it can be read by python using PKCS1.  The ECB is required, otherwise there's junk characters everywhere.

Also, I had to make sure the key was in DER format, and read it with the X509EncodedKeySpec for it to read.  DER = PEM minus the header (----BEGIN ...), and base64 decoded.

Answer (score 2):

Bouncy castle provides padding. If you want for example to make an RSA with PKCS1 padding you have to do this:

```
public static PKCS1Encoding create_rsa_public(RSAKeyParameters PublicKey){
    RSAEngine engine=new RSAEngine();
    PKCS1Encoding encrypto=new PKCS1Encoding(engine);
    encrypto.init(true,PublicKey);
    return encrypto;
}
```

That function will return you an RSA engine with PKCS1Encoding.